# html tag new line issue

Tags: html, frontend

I am new to HTML code , so please bear with me. I have this simple HTML in my website that i am building.

```
<div class="row">
<h2>PRODUCT DETAILS</h2>
du Maurier Special KS - 20 Pack.

</div>

<div class="row">
<h2>BRAND</h2>
Du Maurier is a Canadian brand of cigarettes, produced by Imperial Tobacco Canada, a subsidiary of British American Tobacco. The brand is named after Sir Gerald du Maurier, the noted British actor. The brand is also produced under license by the West Indian Tobacco Company in Trinidad and Tobago.
The brand was launched in the United Kingdom in 1930 after the actor Sir Gerald du Maurier had made requests for "a cigarette less irritating to his throat". He lent his name to the creation of a cigarette brand, the royalties for which he used to pay down his substantial tax liabilities. The tobacco company which launched the brand, Peter Jackson, was a subsidiary of International Tobacco, which was taken over by Gallaher in 1934. In 1979, the brand passed to British American Tobacco, which had owned the trade mark overseas since they acquired Peter Jackson (Overseas) Ltd. in 1955. The brand became the best-selling cigarette brand in Canada with a market share of 40%, and was also sold in various other countries.
```

And the result in the website is
[image]

Notice how "product details" and the details are in the same line. Whereas "Brand " and the description of the brand is in a new line.

If i added more content to "PRODUCT DETAILS" , i can see the output in the website as. Why this inconsistency? Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: What is the css class definition for  "row"

Comment: .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

Comment: the "row" class should behave same for both BRAND and PRODUCT DETAILS if i am not wrong. But if the content is less, PRODUCT DETAILS is behaving different.

Comment: Now your h2 is not 100% width (like display block by default. ) I think your .row should be "display: block", then your h2 will take 100% of block width. and if you need display flex in content, add one more wrapper.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is hard to guess what is causing this.

Comment: @Arnoldas, i think your answer is correct. I tried yours as well. it works fine. What is the significance of keeping the "display: block", as it seems, it works just fine, without the display:block as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with the "row" div class, and i noticed, if i remove the " display: flex;" from the class, it works just fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because your `.row` is `display:flex` it try fit content dynamically. for this reason, `h2` is not 100% width (like display block by default. ). if the content is shorter it goes after `h2`, if longer it goes from the new line.   I think your `.row` should be `display: block`, then your `h2` will take 100% of block width. and if you need display *flex* in content, add one more wrapper.

Comment: I agree. If i replace display:flex with display:block, it works fine. However, it messes up my whole website in other places, where this row css being used. Is there any way i can get this working without changing the css (and just fixing in html code) ?

Comment: it is a bad idea. quick fix just uses not .row but custom class, like .row-custom. with display block, but is a nasty way. all .rows should be displayed block and do one thing: be a row. all other stilling goes to other elements.

Comment: it is always a good idea to do good from the beginning, then recreate all from basics later ;D so my suggestion is made your template nice and clean, not with quick hacks because later you will have more mess.

Comment: The site is already built. I am just adding the products with description. I believe the site was built (i didnt built), to keep the CSS that way, as the whole display cracks, when i change this CSS.

Comment: so just use a custom class to override that flex :)

Comment: just <div class="row custom-class">, than in css .row.custom-class{display: block;}

Comment: I got it. I will have to create another class and use it there.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the browser you are using and its settings. The **closing div tag is missing** for the second div which may cause errors. You should always use

tag or some another tag for displaying text and should not display it without a tag. The p tag will automatically display the text in next line because it is a **[Block Element](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/inline-elements-and-block-elements-in-html-explained/)**.

Comment: The closing tag was there, it was just a copy & paste error.